# websocket-rails connection initialization - dispatcher.state stuck on "connecting"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I am trying to set up a basic websocket from client to my RoR app.  I've used websocket-rails gem for that matter.

I've set up a simple eventMap mapping.
config/events.rb:

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do
  namespace :tasks do
    subscribe :create, :to => TaskController, :with_method => :create
  end
end
```

And a simple controller:
app/controller/task_controller.rb:

```
class TaskController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
  def create
    puts "In task create"
    send_message :create_success, task, :namespace => :tasks
  end
end
```

And finally an initialization from client side:

```
$(function() {
   var task = {
     name: 'Start taking advantage of WebSockets',
     completed: false
   }

   var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/websocket');

   dispatcher.on_open = function(data) {
     alert("on_open");
      console.log('Connection has been established: ', data);
     // You can trigger new server events inside this callback if you wish.
   } 


   $("#ws-test").click(function() {
      dispatcher.trigger('tasks.create', task);
   });

   dispatcher.bind('tasks.create_success', function(task) {
     console.log('successfully created ' + task.name);
    })

});
```

When accessing the page which triggers this code, In network traffic I see the request to ws://localhost:3000/websocket. 
That request is returned with status code **101 Switching Protocols**.
No errors in js nor logs on server side.

This is where I get confused. By RFC 101 means the handshake succeeded, so I thought the connection initialization finished fine.
However, when inspecting and debugging client side, dispatcher.state remains in "connecting". 
When trying to invoke dispatcher.trigger, nothing happens. 
When debugging websocket-rails inner code, during trigger there is a check for dispatcher.state and in case it's not "connected", it pushes it to queue instead of proceeding to handle it.

And this is how it's stuck forever. Tested on Mozilla Firefox 33.0 and on Chrome Version 38.0.2125.104

Any insights would be appreciated.

ruby 2.0.0p576 
Rails 4.1.1 
websocket-rails-0.7.0

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: I ended up starting up a websocket standalone server on a different port.
Everything started working perfectly since then, I never got to solve the initial problem.